# Why my XmlHttpRequest's onload props can not use arrow function

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, arrow-functions

I am learning Ajax and ES6, so i want to bind a function to an onload property
from the XmlHttpRequest obj. At first, i write an anoynymous function and it runs OK. But when i changed the function to arrow syntax, the element with id "text" did not have any value.

```js
//this code runs normally
xhr.onload = function() {
   if (this.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerText = this.responseText;
   } else if (this.status === 404) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerText = "Not Found!";
   }
};


// this code can not run
xhr.onload = () => {
   if (this.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerText = this.responseText;
   } else if (this.status === 404) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerText = "Not Found!";
   }
};
```

I expect my element with id "text" to have value, but when i changed my function into arrow syntax, the element dont receive any value at all.

Comment: `=>` functions don't set `this`

Comment: basic of arrow function.... what is `this` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functionsNo_separate_this

Comment: replacing `this` with `request` does the trick in the arrow version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `this` has no context within the `onload` function. So, when you check the condition `this.status` it is looking for a `this` that is scoped to the containing function. However, arrow functions by nature scope to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions retain the `this`-ness of the outer function. In the top example, `this` refers to `xhr`. In the bottom function, `this` refers to something else (that's impossible to determine from the given code).